# generate json to a unique custom class

Tags: java, json, serialization, initialization, gson

I am very new to java and just started with json...

I have the following json file:

```
"step1": {
    "version": 1,
    "items": {
        "run": false,
        "jump": true
    }
},
"step2": {
    "version": "None",
    "items": {
        "happy": true,
        "sad": false
    }
}
```

I am using Gson in my main like this:

```
Gson gs = new Gson();
Content tmp = gs.fromJson(<json string>, Content.class);
```

my class:

```
public class Content {
    @SerializedName("step1")
    private Step step1;

    @SerializedName("step2")
    private Step step2;
}
```

each step class:

```
public class Step{
    @SerializedName("version")
    private String version;

    @SerializedName("items") 
    ???????
}
```

as you can see the "?????" part is what I am trying to understand - How can I convert the items without needing to know the field name..? meaning to a HashMap/another iterable object..? can I initialize using a method..?

I have tried creating an Item class with a constructor but I do not understand how to use it in this case..

Comment: actually gson is pretty simple to use, you dont need to explicity give the serialization name.... @SerializedName("items")

Comment: So what do I do instead...? How can I convert this file to this class without it...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map<String, Boolean>` to store your items. You `Step` class can be something, like this:

```
public class Step {
    private String version;
    private Map<String, Boolean> items;
}
```

Then you can add your values to the Map:

```
    Step step = new Step();
    step.setVersion("None");

    Map<String, Boolean> items = new HashMap<>();
    items.put("happy", Boolean.TRUE);
    items.put("sad", Boolean.FALSE);
    step.setItems(items);
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is:

```
public class Step{
    @SerializedName("version")
    private String version;

    @SerializedName("items") 
    private HashMap<String,Boolean> items;
}
```